# Join to same table several times in a single query?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to get deeper into "advanced"-SQL'ing but have a slight problem with some pretty basic stuff.
I have one table, where one row refers to another row. There are of course unique id's as well but I'll skip those here:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| field    | name    |      value       |
+----------+----------------------------+
| 1        | aa      |         0        |
| 1        | ab      |         0        |
| 2        | ba      |         1        |
| 2        | bb      |         1        |
| 3        | ca      |         2        |
| 3        | cb      |         2        |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

What I want to accomplish is to get field when I know `field=3 and name= 'ca'`.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT table.value AS parent_id FROM table WHERE table.field=3 AND table.name='ca'
```

That works at some point, it lists everything at 2:field, I need then to find value 1 from the field. BUT if the 2:field does not have any references (as above illustrated, 1:field) then I need the last value which will be 2:field.

How would that be possible in MySQL?

Comment: ohh crap i need to learn SOF code formating as well :S Edit: and so i did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a self-join by using the same table TWICE in the same query, but different ALIAS...

```
select 
      t1.field,
      t1.name,
      t1.value as ThisIsYourParentKey,
      t2.name as ParentName,
      t2.value as GrandParentKey
   from
      YourTable t1
         left join YourTable t2
            on t1.value = t2.field
   where
      t1.name = 'a2'
```

Comment: but if that all is only one table ? (not crossing between 2 different tables)

Comment: could you please explain what t1 & t2 are in that case ?

Comment: @DanelK, that is why the same table name is used TWICE, but with different alias names of "t1" and "t2" to differentiate from the starting entry to allow pointing to it's respective "parent"...

Comment: Thank you so much! I playied around a little  and im starting to see the abstract connections! Sweet :)

Comment: @DanielK: it is easier to see if you use the optional keyword AS between the table and its alias: `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM Table AS t1 JOIN Table AS t2 ON t1.value = t2.field`.  Incidentally, the technique is standard SQL, not specific to MySQL.  (There's a rumour that Oracle does not support the keyword AS in table names, though it does for column aliases.)

Comment: For a brutal case of repeated self-join, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854855/).  The final query uses aliases `lt1` to `lt9` for the main table (`large_table`, obviously abbreviated `lt`).  Note that using aliases systematically can make it easier to read SQL.