# MySQL: Creating Multiple Variables with COALESCE

Tags: mysql, coalesce

By using COALESCE, I can create a temporary variable called comment_votes like so:

```
SELECT comments.*, COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS comment_votes FROM `comments` 
LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id AND 
rs_reputations.target_type = 'Comment' AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 
'comment_votes' AND rs_reputations.active = 1 WHERE (impression_id = 1)
```

I want to create a second variable called impression_votes in the came query. I attempted to do this with:

```
SELECT comments.*, COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS comment_votes 
FROM 'comments' 
    LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON 
        comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id AND 
        rs_reputations.target_type = 'Comment' AND 
        rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'comment_votes' AND 
        rs_reputations.active = 1 
SELECT comments.*, COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS impression_votes 
FROM 'comments' 
    LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON 
    comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id AND
    rs_reputations.target_type = 'Comment' AND
    rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'impression_votes' AND 
    rs_reputations.active = 1 
WHERE
```

This leads to the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

Is what I'm attempting even possible? If so, I seem to be bridging the two SELECT/COALESCE statements improperly. How should I write this?

Comment: COALESCE is an inbuilt function that returns the first non-null value; in your instance, if rs_repuations.value is `NULL`, it will return 0. Your JOIN condition is very strange, what is the foreign key in `rs_repuations` that you are joining on with `comments`?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to keep the code here as simple as possible. I'll update the snippets with the full code. For now, the key is reads like this: comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id

Comment: It's the 'COALESCE . . . AS' statement that I'm after. I don't understand MySQL very well, but it seems that this statement creates a temporary variable that I can call on from my app. I'm doing this to eager load all the votes for my comments.

Comment: Are these 2 separate statements or just one?  If it is one statement, your problem is that you have two select statements with no join or way to concat those statements, are you missing a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MySQL COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function is actually an inbuilt function that returns the first non-null value - it's not a variable, it's a function that is actually supported across a wide variety of database systems.

For example, with the following table:

```
| Id    | Name      | Counter    |
| 1     | lolcat    | NULL       |
| 2     | codez     | 1          |
```

The sql statement:

```
SELECT Id, Name, COALESCE(counter, 0) AS NonNullCounter FROM table
```

will return the results:

```
| Id    | Name      | NonNullCounter |
| 1     | lolcat    | 0              |
| 2     | codez     | 1              |
```

In this instance, the NULL value has been replaced by 0.

This is useful for you as, if you don't yet have any matching rows in rs_reputations for the row in comments, the `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` for the column `rs_repuations.value`, which is then replaced by `0` by `COALESCE`.

If you are new to JOINs then there is a great [visual guide by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Your first query can is actually:

```
SELECT     comments.*, 
           COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS comment_votes 
FROM       comments 
LEFT JOIN   rs_reputations ON comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id 
                           AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'comment_votes' 
WHERE       impression_id = 1;
```

**CHOICE 1 - UNION**

You have a couple of choices - you can either [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) your results together like this:

```
SELECT     comments.*, 
           COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS votes,
           'comment_votes' AS vote_type 
FROM       comments 
LEFT JOIN   rs_reputations ON comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id 
                           AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'comment_votes' 
WHERE       impression_id = 1

UNION

SELECT     comments.*, 
           COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS votes,
           'impression_votes' as vote_type 
FROM       comments 
LEFT JOIN   rs_reputations ON comments.id = rs_reputations.target_id 
                           AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'impression_votes' 
WHERE       impression_id = 1;
```

In this instance your results will look like this:

```
|comments_columns|votes|vote_type       |
| *              |12   |comment_vote    |
| *              |2    |impression_vote |
```

**CHOICE 2 - JOIN ON TO THE SAME TABLE TWICE**

Or you can self join onto the same table twice by [using the same table name but a different alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958610/join-to-same-table-several-times-in-a-single-query):

```
SELECT     comments.*, 
           COALESCE(CommentRep.value, 0) AS comment_votes,
           COALESCE(ImpressionRep.value, 0) AS impression_votes,
FROM       comments 
LEFT JOIN   rs_reputations AS CommentRep ON comments.id = CommentRep.target_id 
                           AND CommentRep.reputation_name = 'comment_votes' 
LEFT JOIN   rs_reputations AS ImpressionRep ON comments.id = ImpressionRep.target_id 
                           AND ImpressionRep.reputation_name = 'impression_votes'
WHERE       CommentRep.impression_id = 1
AND         ImpressionRep.impression_id = 1
```

In this instance your results will look like this:

```
|comments_columns|comment_votes|impression_votes|
| *              |12           |0               |
| *              |2            |6               |
```

Finally (phew) the reason you have an error in your original SQL is that you are chaining two SELECT statements together without actually relating them - the SQL doesn't really make sense in this instance as you need to logically relate them (either via a UNION or a repeated join as per above.

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly thorough answer, and I'd give you more than one upvote if I could. Both approaches work, but the first helps streamline my app in other ways, so I'm going with it. Thanks again!